# How to GET Employee Absences data from HCM Fusion by sending two dates in REST API query parameter

Tags: oracle, api, rest, query-string, fusion

I would like to GET employee last 2 months and future 2 months absences data.

REST API: https://host:port/hcmRestApi/resources/11.13.18.05/absences

https://host:port/hcmRestApi/resources/11.13.18.05/absences?q=startDate between '2018-09-22' and '2018-09-25'
https://host:port/hcmRestApi/resources/11.13.18.05/absences?q=startDate>2018-09-22;startDate<2018-09-25

Tried different options but no luck. Please advise!

Thank you!

Comment: I tried using the startDate and endDate fields but no luck. https://host:port/hcmRestApi/resources/11.13.18.05/absences?q=startDate>2018-09-01%26endDate<2018-09-31 getting error An instance of type java.sql.Date cannot be created from string 2018-09-01&endDate<2018-09-31. The string value must be in format YYYY-MM-DD.

Comment: Working https://host:port/hcmRestApi/resources/11.13.18.05/absences?q=startDate>2021-04-02;endDate<2021-04-15 but I want to know how can we get the data between two startDates

Answer (score 0):

This REST API helped me to GET Employee Absence data using two dates.

https://xxxxxxx.oraclecloud.com:443/hcmRestApi/resources/11.13.18.05/absences?finder=findByAbsStartAndEndDate;startDate=2021-04-01,endDate=2021-04-30&orderBy=personId:asc

for more details please refer to the link
https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/saas/human-resources/21b/farws/op-absences-get.html

Thank you!